# Spring Boot Hibernate Concurrent Transactions causing data loss on Update request

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

**The problem is when multiple calls concurrently occur on update request, the data that should be saved is missing from db. From my point of view, I am having some problems with Hibernate Isolation, because I have tried adding Transactional at the top of my service method, but it is throwing exception 'ERROR: could not serialize access due to concurrent update'**

> The case I am having problem with is following: there is an endpoint which takes an ID and updates a table's data on M-to-M relationship. So the thing is that, sometimes multiple concurrent requests (ex req 1,2,3) causing middle one to be lost (2) along the way.

---

> So far I have used @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE). But it is throwing error on requests 2 and 3 not saving data at all.

---

> My question is that, which combination should I choose for propagation and isolation in order to overcome this issue

```
    @PostMapping("/upload_answer", produces = ["application/json"])
    @ApiOperation("UploadAnswer")
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
    fun uploadAnswer(
        @Valid @RequestBody modelDTO: LessonAssessmentAnswerDTO,
        principal: Principal)
            //:  AssessmentDTO
            : MutableList<LessonAssessmentDetailsDTO>
    {
        val curUsername = principal.name

        val resultDTOs = mutableListOf<LessonAssessmentDetailsDTO>()

        val student = _studentService.getByUsername(curUsername)
            ?: throw NotFoundException()

        var lessonID = 0L

        if (modelDTO.assessment_id == null)
        {
            if (modelDTO.lesson_id == null)
                throw BadRequestException()

            val lesson = _lessonService.getById(modelDTO.lesson_id!!)
                ?: throw NotFoundException()
            lessonID = lesson.id!!

            val existingAssessments = student.lessonAssessments.stream().filter {
                it.lesson.id == lesson.id && it.attempt == 1
            }.collect(Collectors.toList())

            if (existingAssessments.count() > 0)
                throw BadRequestException()

            val assessment = MSStudentLessonAssessment()
            assessment.student = student
            assessment.lesson = lesson
            assessment.attempt = 1

            if (modelDTO.new_attachments.count() > 0)
            {
                val attachmentsToBeUpdated = baseFileUploaderAttachmentService
                    .findAllById(modelDTO.new_attachments)
                attachmentsToBeUpdated.map { it.isAttached = true }

                assessment.attachments.addAll(attachmentsToBeUpdated)
                assessment.dateAttachmentUploaded = Date().time

                prepareData(principal, assessment)
                val result = assessmentRepo.save(assessment)
                student.lessonAssessments.add(result)
                studentRepo.saveAndFlush(student)
                //result = assessment
            }
            else
                throw BadRequestException()
        }
        else
        {
            val assessment = _assessmentService.getById(modelDTO.assessment_id!!)
                ?: throw NotFoundException()

            if (assessment.student.id != student.id
                || assessment.mark != null)
                throw BadRequestException()

            lessonID = assessment.lesson.id!!

            if (modelDTO.deleted_attachments.isNotEmpty())
            {
                val deletedAttachments = baseFileUploaderAttachmentService
                    .findAllById(modelDTO.deleted_attachments)

                deletedAttachments.map {
                    it.deleted = true
                    it.active = false
                }
                assessment.attachments.removeAll(deletedAttachments)
            }

            if (modelDTO.new_attachments.count() > 0)
            {
                val attachmentsToBeUpdated = baseFileUploaderAttachmentService
                    .findAllById(modelDTO.new_attachments)
                attachmentsToBeUpdated.map { it.isAttached = true }

                assessment.attachments.addAll(attachmentsToBeUpdated)
                assessment.dateAttachmentUploaded = Date().time
            }

//            if (_assessmentService.update(assessment, curUsername))
                //result = assessment
//            else
//                throw InternalServerErrorException()

            assessmentRepo.save(assessment)
        }

        val assessments = student.lessonAssessments.filter {
            it.lesson.id == lessonID
        }

        if (assessments.count() > 0)
        {
            for (item in assessments)
            {
                resultDTOs.add(LessonAssessmentDetailsDTO().toDTO(item))
            }
        }

        return resultDTOs
    }
```

> If anythingn is missing in my question, let me know i will update it, Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It seems that you are calling the DAO layer directly from your Controller layer. This should not be done. You should call a service layer that handles the transaction.

Comment: There is no service layer here, Should i create new service and put all codes there and put transactional on the top of the method of that service? @Shashank

Comment: Yes. Please try that and let me know if it works.

Comment: My friend it did not work I have created new service and put all code inside it and put transactional on it, still the same exception being thrown @Shashank